# Find length of array of strings in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have a dynamic array of c-strings

`char **my_strings = (char**)malloc(50 * sizeof(char*));`

and I want to find it's actual length (how many strings it actually contains). How can I do this?

Comment: Pass the size, or NULL-terminate the array, or both.

Comment: Read [ask] and fdollow the advice. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: You don't have an array of c-strings. You have a pointer to pointers of char. While similar, not the entirely same thing.

Comment: @StoryTeller I tried to do this, but it doesn't work : `while (!strings[count] == NULL) count++;`

Comment: `while (strings[count])` OR `while (strings[count] != NULL)`. Your condition is just plain wrong.

Comment: You have potentially 50 strings. But there is no code showing how many pointer elements of the array you have used.

Comment: You can do it any way you want to. There's no "one right way". (Also, your question is very vague about what you really want to know. Allocated size? Number of strings it actually contains? Something else?)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz count a few of them

Comment: @Kiramm After the line of code you showed in your question, how many strings does it actually contain? Zero, because you never put any strings in there? 50, because there's space for 50? Or any number, since the garbage in the memory you allocated may or may not contain strings? Your question is still vague about what you want to know.

Comment: @StoryTeller I'd advocate "Pass the size, or NULL-terminate the array, but not both." unless one likes belt and suspenders coding.  [Various views](http://stackoverflow.com/q/767952/2410359)

Comment: @chux - Well, there is the example of `main`... So it's not unheard of

Comment: @StoryTeller Oh yes. C has something for every coding style in its long history. `argv[argc]` is `NULL` C11 §5.1.2.2.1 2,   C also set the last element to `NULL`.  Is that redundant?  Did I ask that before?  Courtesy of [department of redundancy department](https://www.google.com/search?q=department+of+redundancy+department&client=opera&hs=1l8&sa=X&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&ved=0ahUKEwiTzsHCv-jSAhUGyWMKHfUvAnEQ7AkINQ&biw=1280&bih=675)  ;-) ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the array be terminated with a NULL pointer, then just do:

```
size_t count = 0;
while (my_strings[count] != NULL) {
    ++count;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't tell: it's your job to keep track of the size, or to use a magic value (NULL, say) to mark the final element.

Note that the c runtime probably keeps track of the amount of memory allocated, but this is not exposed to you in any portable way.

Answer (score 0):

A `char *` is not a "string": it is a **pointer**. Strings are arrays where one of its elements is `'\0'`.

Pointers and arrays are different!

Check section 6 of the [c-faq](http://c-faq.com/).