# why does strcmp() not work in my program?

Tags: c, strcmp, string.h

I am writing a program that takes multiple words as input and determines which word would come first and last if the words were listed in dictionary order. However my program does not fully work just yet.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void getword(void);

char str[20];
char smallest[20];
char largest[20];

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    while (strlen(str) != 4) {
        getword();

        if (strcmp(str, smallest) < 0) {
            strcpy(smallest, str);
        } else
        if (strcmp(str, largest) > 0) {
            strcpy(largest, str);
        }
    }

    printf("smallest:%s\nlargest:%s\n", smallest,largest);

    return 0;
}

void getword(void) {
     printf("Enter a word: ");
     scanf("%s", str);
}
```

The user must enter words, I will assume the words are no longer than 20 characters long and if the user enters a 4 letter word then the program will stop.

The problem I have is that the first `if` statement (tests for smallest word in dictionary order) does not work. When the program is ran the output looks like this:

```
Enter a word: dog
Enter a word: zebra
Enter a word: rabbit
Enter a word: catfish
Enter a word: walrus
Enter a word: cat
Enter a word: fish
smallest:
largest:zebra
```

As you can see the 'smallest' word is not picked up and a simple printf statement in the if statement shows me that my program doesn't even enter the if statement at all, why is this?

Comment: What do you think are the *initial* values for smallest and largest?

Comment: Your `smallest[20]` is an empty character array. Then you compare the empty against something, so the empty win. This is why you don't see any output at the smallest.

Comment: "will assume the words are no longer than 20 characters" --> off by 1.  "no longer than 19".  Rather than assume, use `fgets()`instead of `scanf()` and lop off the read `'\n'`.

Comment: The first value you enter is both the smallest _and_ the largest to date.  And, just FYI, `strcmp()` is working fine — it is your expectations that are mismatched with the logic you've written.

Comment: I think you want `char smallest[20] = "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~";`

Comment: Or: always assign them *both* at the first iteration.

Comment: Or: initialise before the loop, using memset() with 0xff and 0.

Comment: `while (strlen(str) != 4){` what do you think `str` contains at the start of main?

Comment: proprogrammer32987, Try `char smallest[20] = { 255 };`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problems with STRCPY and STRCMP when finding the smallest and largest problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47842430/problems-with-strcpy-and-strcmp-when-finding-the-smallest-and-largest-problems)

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems:

- you test the length of `str` **before** reading the word from the user, hence the 4 letter word will be handled.
- you should protect the `scanf("%s", str)` as `scanf("%19s", str)` to avoid buffer overflow if a word longer than 19 characters is entered.
- `smallest` is a global variable, thus is initialized as an empty string, so it is always smaller than any non empty input. You should avoid global variables.
- if a single word in input, it will be both the smallest and the largest word, hence you should not have an `else` statement or make a special case of the first word.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// read a word from the user, return the word length
int getword(char *str) {
    printf("Enter a word: ");
    *str = '\0';
    scanf("%19s", str);
    return strlen(str);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char str[20];
    char smallest[20] = "";
    char largest[20] = "";

    while (getword(str) != 4) {
        if (*smallest == '\0' || strcmp(str, smallest) < 0) {
            strcpy(smallest, str);
        }
        if (strcmp(str, largest) > 0) {
            strcpy(largest, str);
        }
    }
    printf("smallest:%s\n", smallest);
    printf("largest:%s\n", largest);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing `str` with `smallest` or `largest`. But the problem is `smallest` and `largest` are initialized to empty string(being declared as global). That means `str` may contain `"Dog"/"Zebra"/"cat"/"anything"` while `smallest` contains `""`(empty string). In this case, `(strcmp(str,smallest) < 0)` will always be `false`. As a result `smallest` will always remain same and in the end, result will be `smallest = ""`. Your program is doing right that and printing empty string as result of smallest.

What you can do is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void getword(void);

char str[20];      //str = ""
char smallest[20]; //smallest= ""
char largest[20];  //largest = ""


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //>--------extra part begins-->---------------
    scanf("%s", smallest);
    strcpy(largest,smallest);
    //<--------extra part ends--<---------------

    while (strlen(str) != 4)
    {
      getword();

      if (strcmp(str,smallest) < 0)
      {
          strcpy(smallest,str);
      }

      else if (strcmp(str, largest) > 0)
      {
          strcpy(largest,str);
      }
 }

    printf("smallest:%s\nlargest:%s\n", smallest,largest);

    return 0;
}

void getword(void){
     printf("Enter a word: ");
     scanf("%s", str);
}
```

Comment: "But the problem is smallest and largest are not initialized. " --> with OP's `char smallest[20]; char largest[20];` outside a function, both are fully initialized to all zeros.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica does any variable declared outside a function is initialized to zero? I didn't know about it?

Comment: Global variables as well as static local variables without an initializer are initialized to the `0` value of their type before the `main` function is run. integers are initialized to `0`, floating point objects to `0.0`, pointers to the null pointer. Aggregates have all member initialized this way.  For `unions`, the first member is initialized. Note that this may be different from initializing objects to all bits zero as performed by `calloc` and `memset`, but for most current architectures, `0.0` and the null pointers have all their bits cleared.